# XML Parsing failed for special characters

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, obiee

I am using below script to parse my ';' separated inputs into different rows:
(SELECT
    EXTRACT (VALUE (d), '//row/text()').getstringval ()
FROM
    (SELECT XMLTYPE (''|| REPLACE ('VALUEOF(NQ_SESSION.p_acct)', ';', '')|| '') AS xmlval
    FROM DUAL) x,
TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x.xmlval, '/rows/row'))) d)

This code fails when it comes across an input for p_acct with '&' value, i.e. if p_acct is something like 'AT&T'. How can I make sure that those strings too are processed inot different rows.

Thanks,
Yada.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace special  characters

In your example AT&T needs to be AT%26T

Code

```
REPLACE(string ‘&’, ‘%26′)
```

Comment: I need to give this as input for a SQL..the above replace changes my string input!!